# How do I use a variable name correctly in re.sub

Tags: python

I'm a frustrated Python novice. I'm trying to undestand why my code won't insert a tab after the taxonomy value (SSLKT6_7.6.1) in the following lines in a text file:

support/knowledgecenter/                cs/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mam.doc/gp_finmgr/c_processes.html

support/knowledgecenter/                de/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mam.doc/overview/c_new_config.html

The commented line in the code does enter a tab after 'support/knowledgecenter/'

Thank you.

```
print ("Enter taxonomy: ")

taxonomy  = input( "> " )

with open( fileToSearch, "r+" ) as file:
  for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
  string4=line

  #result = re.sub('(knowledgecenter/)(.*?/' + re.escape(taxonomy) + ')', r'\1\t\2', line)

  result1 = re.sub('(knowledgecenter/)''(' + re.escape(taxonomy) + ')', r'\1\t\2', line)

 file.write(result1)

 fileinput.close
```

Comment: There is a "cs/" or "de/" between "knowledgecenter/" and the taxonomy value.

Answer (score 0):

If the `"SSLKT6_7.6.1"` is always the forth element of the addresses, the you can use the [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method to split the addresses by forward slashes.

Concatenate the tab to the forth element of the list *(at index `3`)*, and use the [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) method to join the list by slashes:

```
strings = ["support/knowledgecenter/ cs/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mam.doc/gp_finmgr/c_processes.html", "support/knowledgecenter/ de/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mam.doc/overview/c_new_config.html"]
for s in strings:
    s = s.split("/")
    s[3] += "\t"
    print("/".join(s))
```

Output:

```
support/knowledgecenter/ cs/SSLKT6_7.6.1    /com.ibm.mam.doc/gp_finmgr/c_processes.html
support/knowledgecenter/ de/SSLKT6_7.6.1    /com.ibm.mam.doc/overview/c_new_config.html
```

If the number of elements before the `"SSLKT6_7.6.1"` is unknown, you can use the [`list.index()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method to find the index of the `"knowledgecenter"` element, and add `2` to the returned index, and judging by how you structured your regex pattern, that will return the index of the `"SSLKT6_7.6.1"`:

```
strings = ["support/knowledgecenter/ cs/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mam.doc/gp_finmgr/c_processes.html", "support/knowledgecenter/ de/SSLKT6_7.6.1/com.ibm.mam.doc/overview/c_new_config.html"]
for s in strings:
    s = s.split("/")
    s[s.index("knowledgecenter") + 2] += "\t"
    print("/".join(s))
```

Output:

```
support/knowledgecenter/ cs/SSLKT6_7.6.1    /com.ibm.mam.doc/gp_finmgr/c_processes.html
support/knowledgecenter/ de/SSLKT6_7.6.1    /com.ibm.mam.doc/overview/c_new_config.html
```